# thread waits forever for notification case

Tags: java, multithreading, happens-before

Is it possible in any cases get 'waiting forever' case in ThreadA. I mean notification executes faster than `b.sync.wait();`

```
class ThreadA {
      public static void main(String [] args) {
         ThreadB b = new ThreadB();

         b.start();

         synchronized(b.sync) 
         {
            try 
            {
               System.out.println("Waiting for b to complete...");
               b.sync.wait();
               System.out.println("waiting done");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}         
         }
      }
}

class ThreadB extends Thread {   
     int total=0; 
     Integer sync = new Integer(1);
     public void run() {


        synchronized(sync) 
        {
           sync.notify();
        }  
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. Once you call `b.start()` scheduler may choose to run thread B, and it will immediately obtain lock and call notify, when thread A is not waiting on the lock. In this situation threat A will later obtain lock and keep on waiting forever.

In case you need deterministic behavior, you should call `b.start()` only after you've started waiting for notification.

Comment: That means in my situation, in case I need avoid sleeping forewer I must to call b.start() in some ThreadC while waiting in ThreadA.

Comment: @user1501700 That's right. In general, using `wait()` and `notify()` is discouraged nowadays, since we have `java.util.concurrent` package. `CountDownLatch`, for example, would do just what you need (`await()` in A, `countDown()` in B) without synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee to the order of execution of your threads. It is possible (and, as far as I remember, how threads tend to work in Java) that the **notification will happen before the wait() is invoked**.

You can almost never assume that something will happen before another thing.

For a list of actions that create happens-before relationships, refer to: [Java Memory Visibility](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility) or Chapter 17 of [The Java™ Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/jls7.pdf)